# How do i calculate accuracy of my ANN in this case

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras

I am running the following code. I want to calculate accuracy of my ANN for test data. I am using windows platfrom, python 3.5

```
import numpy 
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
dataset=pd.read_csv('main.csv')
dataset=dataset.fillna(0)
X=dataset.iloc[:, 0:6].values
#X = X[numpy.logical_not(numpy.isnan(X))]
y=dataset.iloc[:, 6:8].values
#y = y[numpy.logical_not(numpy.isnan(y))]
#regr = LinearRegression()
#regr.fit(numpy.transpose(numpy.matrix(X)), numpy.transpose(numpy.matrix(y)))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.24,random_state=0)
```

## create model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal'))
```

## Compile model

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=5, epochs=5)

y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
```

Now, i want to calculate the accuracy of y_pred. Any help will be appreciated.
The above code is self explanatory. I am currently using only 5 epochs just for experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Keras already implements metrics such as accuracy, so you just need to change the `model.compile` line to:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',
              metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

Then training and validation accuracy (in the [0, 1] range) will be presented at the progress bar during training, and you can compute accuracy with `model.evaluate` as well, which will return a tuple of loss and metrics (accuracy in this case).

Comment: Maybe a reminder that, normally, MSE loss & accuracy do not go together, as we have discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse), would be useful here

Answer (score 0):

Besides the suggestion of using `keras`. You can compute the accuracy using `scikit-learn` as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

For more information, check the documentation : [sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although in a narrow technical sense both answers already provided are correct, there is a more general issue with your question which affects the essence of it: are you in a regression or a classification context?

- If you are in a *regression* context (as implied by your `loss='mean_squared_error'` and the linear activation in your output layer), then the simple augmentation of model compilation

  ```
  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',
        metrics = ["accuracy"])
  ```

  will, as Matias says, provide the accuracy. Nevertheless, **accuracy is meaningless in a regression setting**; see the answer & discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577) for more details.
- If you are in a *classification* context (as implied by your wish to calculate the accuracy, which is meaningful only in classification), then your loss function should not be the MSE, but the cross-entropy instead, plus that the activation of your last layer should not be linear.

Answer (score -1):

to compute accuracy we can use `model.evaluate` function