# Keras accuracy calculation and meaning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am detecting objects using CNN and keras

When i test/train model it outputs acc and loss.

I am using MSE loss functions so i understand what loss mean, however what is accuracy and how is it calculated? I have 4000 loss and accuracy 80% which is stupid. It does not detect object 80% correctly. What does it mean and how is it calcualted then?

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you using categorical accuracy or binary accuracy

Comment: I am using the default one  model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: mse loss is for regression not classification.

Comment: yes but the acc is still there so how is it calcualated?

Comment: Thats the point. It's not calculated correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse)