# Keras validation accuracy won't go over 75% and prediction performs bad

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bmdFpQHq7dmS0vrxJKd6ZgJcfujwEJTF/view?usp=sharing) dataset to make pollution prediction (NO2) using keras library. I made interpolation on missing data, one hot encoding on wind direction.
Divided records on train/validation and test set an gave them to keras through a batch generator after doing Normalization through MinMaxScaler

This are some model I used but none of them seems to go over 75% of validation accuracy and prediction made are really bad:

```
#### MODEL TYPE DECLARATION AND CONFIGURATION 
######################################

code_name = {-1: "linear", 0: "ann_base_single", 1 : "ann_base_multi", 
             2 : "gru_single_layer", 3 : "gru_single_layer_w_dropout", 4 : "gru_multi_layer", 5 : "gru_multi_layer_2",
             6 : "lstm_single_layer", 7 : "lstm_single_layer_w_dropout", 8: "lstm_multi_layer", 9 : "lstm_multi_layer_2"}
model_type = 20

model = Sequential()
if model_type == -1:
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='linear'))
elif model_type == 0:
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 1:
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 2:
    model.add(layers.GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 3:
    model.add(layers.GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 4:
    model.add(layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.GRU(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 5:
    model.add(layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.GRU(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(layers.GRU(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 6:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 7:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 8:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 9:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mae', metrics=[metrics.mae, 'accuracy'])
model.summary()

timenow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_")
run_name = '{7}_Nodes_{0}-Units_{1}-shift_steps_{2}-aq_parameter_{3}-train_split_{4}-batch_size_{5}-sequence_length_{6}'.format(code_name[model_type], hidden_layer_size, shift_steps, aq_parameter, train_split, batch_size, sequence_length, timenow)
path_checkpoint = 'checkpoints\\{0}.keras'.format(run_name)

#### CALLBACK DECLARATION #######################################

callback_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=path_checkpoint,
                                      monitor='val_loss',
                                      verbose=1,
                                      save_weights_only=True,
                                      save_best_only=True)

callback_early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                        patience=4, verbose=1)

callback_reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                                       factor=0.1,
                                       min_lr=1e-5,
                                       patience=3,
                                       verbose=1)

callbacks = [callback_checkpoint,
             callback_early_stopping,
             callback_reduce_lr,
             callback_reset_states]


#### FITTING DATA INTO MODEL

    history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=int(train_data_size / batch_size),
                              epochs=epochs,
                              validation_data=validation_data,
                              callbacks = callbacks,
                              shuffle= False)
```

Followed [this](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/23_Time-Series-Prediction.ipynb) tutorial.

[image: enter]
[image: enter]
[image: enter]

Comment: What excactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to know, how to improve this model so it can be over 75% val_acc and made accurate prevision... I'm new to machine learning and maybe I made some mistakes on data or something else

Comment: @desertnaut how are you supposed to understand a neural network problem without having a full panorama of it?
People usually downvote due to poor info, not the opposite

Comment: Please *do read the link* (especially *Why this is a problem* & *Why this is worth a downvote*), as well as [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); some hints: 1) which one of your 22 (!) models produces these graphs? 2) is it `stateful` or not? 3) are the Tensorboard callbacks really necessary for understanding your *problem*? SO does not work by just throwing all your code into the question, and it requires some additional steps from your side, so as to help us in order to help *you*...

Comment: And how can you combine MAE (a regression metric) with accuracy (a classification one)? Is your problem a regression or a classification one? It seems to be the former, in which case **accuracy is meaningless**...

Comment: 1) I wrote so many model because all of them (more or less) produces the problem. I don't know how to determine which one is better 
2) Stateful need to be set true for the model with stateful model enabled and to switch between fit_generator calls (with generator even for validating or not) 
3) tensorboard callback could be removed from the code section (removed)
4) it's a regression problem since I need to predict a NO2 value (numerical and not categorical) could you explain why these two metrics could not be used together? People on discussion uses both

Comment: Which people on which discussion? Before proceeding to rather complicated ML attempts, like the one you present here, pls *do* take some time to **familiarize yourself with the fundamental concepts**; see my answer at [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577) (applicable for MAE, too), as well as the comments in the OP there...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite comprehensive , but isn't analytical enough , for you to pinpoint what is exactly is causing your prediction to stay at the range of 75%.

Try to implement some callback functions of keras , so that you can store the model at different stages , and get to know how the performance changes through each layer.

[Keras functionality of callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/)

[Model Checkpoint Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/check-point-deep-learning-models-keras/)

You will have to extend your code in the Callack Declaration section, taking into account 22 types of models being compared, and check how each model pans out.

Comment: Since I'm already using this callback from the beginnin I can't face a way to compare all the models at the same time... Are you suggesting to train on a while{} all the model and then compare checkpoints?

Comment: Yes trying to compare the checkpoints ,by inserting the models inside a while{} , might be the solution.