# MNIST Classification: mean_squared_error loss function and tanh activation function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I changed the [getting started example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/) of Tensorflow as following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import numpy as np
import commons as cm
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
  # tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
  # tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
               loss='mean_squared_error',
              # loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = cm.Histories()
h= model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, callbacks=[history])
print("history:", history.losses)
cm.plot_history(h)
# cm.plot(history.losses, history.aucs)


test_predictions = model.predict(x_test)


# Compute confusion matrix
pred = np.argmax(test_predictions,axis=1)
pred2 = model.predict_classes(x_test)
confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred)
cm.draw_confusion(confusion,range(10))
```

With its default parameters:

- `relu` activation at hidden layers,
- `softmax` at the output layer and
- `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function,

it works fine and the prediction for all digits are above 99%

However with my parameters: `tanh` activation function and `mean_squared_error` loss function it just predict `0` for all test samples:

[image]

I wonder what is the problem? The accuracy rate is increasing for each epoch and it reaches 99% and loss is about 20

Comment: MSE is not an appropriate loss function for classification problems, as in your case; you may find this thread useful: [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577)

Comment: My output target variable Y consists of floating values lying between -1 and 1.

Hence, I am willing to use 'tanh' activation function, at the last layer of my keras deep learning model.

Which 'loss function' is preferred in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the proper loss function for your data. Here you have a categorical output, so you need to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, but also set `from_logits` without any activation for the last layer.

If you need to use `tanh` as your output, then you can use MSE with a one-hot encoded version of your labels + rescaling.

Comment: Thanks, but I had to use those functions and measure their performance. I think my mistake is that I should evaluate the categorial output in another way.

Comment: Using `tanh` for a logits output doesn't make sense (it's not between 0 and 1, and the cost functions expect unbounded values). What do you mean by "had to use thse functions"? If you want to use MSE error, use a sigmoid output, clamp the categories at (1e-7, 1-1e-7) to avoid divergence and try again. But be aware that the results won't sum to one anymore.

Comment: It's an assignment and those things are in the assignment definition, so I can't use other methods, unless they are equivalent with what I do. I think I reached a solution

Comment: Change class then? Seems like this doesn't teach you the right practices.

Comment: I guess I should convert the output to a matrix using `keras.utils.to_categorical`. However, I am not sure if it can make bipolar values for the matrix

Comment: It encodes values to 0-1. You still then need to change the output activation fucntion, tanh DOESN'T work for values of 0 and 1.

Comment: Right! I just asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374154/how-to-convert-a-binary-matrix-to-a-bipolar-one-in-python to know of an easy way to do that.

Comment: I converted the matrix as you said, and now the classification works with `tanh`!

Comment: OK, let me modify the answer a little bit then.

Comment: if I rescale training data,`x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0`, it doesn't work! do you know why?

Comment: You said it worked? And you have the rescaling in your code here? Did you rescale twice?

Comment: Sorry, I tested it with a related tutorial, similar above solution. Later I found that he did not resale inputs.

Comment: Consider the code above, converts output to categorical and remove rescaling input so it works. But why?

Comment: That actually may not matter, you are not in an autoencoder. The different scale may be required to get a good gradient at the beginning, it all depends on the initialization.

Comment: :( but it's again among the practice conditions. It may works cause accuracy is high but the confusion matrix shows low and messed results.

Comment: The scaling of the inputs is linked to the scaling of the initial weights of the layer. they are both scaled in opposite of one another. There is no practice that forbids you to scale or not scale them for a classification network.

Comment: Oops, I found the error! if you check my code, in two ways I checked the `test_predictions`, the `pred2` I must use in my new conditions.

Comment: My output target variable Y consists of floating values lying between -1 and 1.

Hence, I am willing to use 'tanh' activation function, at the last layer of my keras deep learning model.

Which 'loss function' is preferred in this case?

Comment: @AnuragGupta This would be a new question, and better on datascience.SE or stats.SE.