# How to convert a binary matrix to a bipolar one in python

Tags: python, keras

There is a function in [Keras](https://keras.io/utils/) to generate a binary matrix for an array of labels:

```
# Consider an array of 5 labels out of a set of 3 classes {0, 1, 2}:
> labels
array([0, 2, 1, 2, 0])
# `to_categorical` converts this into a matrix with as many
# columns as there are classes. The number of rows
# stays the same.
> to_categorical(labels)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

I need the above functionality, but having `-1` instead of zeros. I didn't find any option or other functions to do it. Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rescale your data:

```
2*to_categorical(labels)-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 1.],
                [0., 1., 0.],
                [0., 0., 1.],
                [1., 0., 0.]])

arr[np.isclose(arr, 0)] = -1
print(arr)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1.  1.]
 [-1.  1. -1.]
 [-1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1. -1. -1.]]
```