# Keras validation accuracy is 0, and stays constant throughout the training

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, time-series, lstm

I am doing a time series analysis using Tensorflow/ Keras in Python.
The overall LSTM model looks like,

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(25, input_shape = (1,1), activation =    'relu', dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['acc'])
tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()))
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', mode='max', verbose=1, patience=50)
mc = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('/home/sukriti/best_model.h5',   monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_best_only=True)
history = model.fit(trainX_3d, trainY_1d, epochs=50, batch_size=10, verbose=2, validation_data = (testX_3d, testY_1d), callbacks=[mc, es, tensorboard])
```

I am having the following outcome,

```
Train on 14015 samples, validate on 3503 samples
Epoch 1/50
- 3s - loss: 0.0222 - acc: 7.1352e-05 - val_loss: 0.0064 - val_acc:  0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/50
- 2s - loss: 0.0120 - acc: 7.1352e-05 - val_loss: 0.0054 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/50
- 2s - loss: 0.0108 - acc: 7.1352e-05 - val_loss: 0.0047 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Now the `val_acc` remains unchanged. Is it normal?
what does it signify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As signified by `loss = 'mean_squared_error'`, you are in a *regression* setting, where **accuracy is meaningless** (it is meaningful only in *classification* problems).

Unfortunately, Keras will not "protect" you in such a case, insisting in computing and reporting back an "accuracy", despite the fact that it is meaningless and inappropriate for your problem - see my answer in [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577)

You should simply remove `metrics=['acc']` from your model compilation, and don't bother - in regression settings, MSE itself can (and usually does) serve also as the performance metric.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had validation accuracy of 0.0000e+00 throughout training (using Keras and CNTK-GPU backend) when my batch size was 64 but there were only 120 samples in my validation set (divided into three classes). After I changed the batch size to 60, I got normal accuracy values.

Comment: You got "normal" accuracy values in a *regression* setting (such as here), where accuracy is meaningless?

Answer (score 0):

It will not improve with changing batch size or with metrics. I had the same problem but when I shuffled my training and validation data set 0.0000e+00 gone.

Comment: Here `accuracy` was used for a **regression** problem, so it has nothing to do with `shuffle = True` here.