# Why my keras code doesn't show the accuracy value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

When I train the model,I can't get my accuracy

```
model.fit(train, train_label,
          batch_size=64,
          epochs=12,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(test, test_label))
```

when I train the data,it shows like that:

```
Epoch 1/12
8000/8000 [==============================] - 166s 21ms/step - loss: 0.4743 - val_loss: 0.2727
```

It shows the number of loss, but no accuracy.

When I evaluate,

```
score = model.evaluate(test, test_label, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

it tells me that:

```
 IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I don't know why the score is a scalar variable.

How can I get my accuracy?

Answer (score 8):

When you compile a Keras model, you specify the metrics you want to monitor on this model. From the [documentation](https://keras.io/metrics/):

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
```

Here we have specified that we would like the model to output Mean Absolute Error (`mae`) and Accuracy (`acc`).

By default your model only tracks loss. You have only one metric, therefore the result of `.evaluate` is a single number (scalar) and doesn't support indexing, hence the error.

Comment: Good job (+1), but notice that in regression settings (i.e. `mse`or `mae` loss) we normally don't use accuracy, which is a classification setting & meaningless in regression; see [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577). Didn't know though that this is how it is suggested in Keras docs - I'll open an issue at Github...