# can the accuracy measure val_acc be trusted?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, evaluation

Building a sequence

```
simple_seq= [x for x in list(range(1000)) if x % 3 == 0]
```

after reshape and split

```
x_train, x_test shape = (159, 5, 1)
y_train, y_test shape = (159, 2)
```

Model

```
model = Sequential(name='acc_test')
model.add(Conv1D(
  kernel_size = 2,
  filters= 128,
  strides= 1,
  use_bias= True,
  activation= 'relu',
  padding='same', 
  input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))

model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size =(2), strides= [1]))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2))

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile( optimizer= optimizer, loss= 'mse',  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Train

```
hist = model.fit(
          x=x_train, 
          y = y_train, 
          epochs=100, 
          validation_split=0.2)
```

The Result:

```
Epoch 100/100
127/127 [==============================] - 0s 133us/sample - loss: 0.0096 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.6305 - val_acc: 1.0000
```

But if using this model to predict:

```
x_test[-1:] = array([[[9981],
        [9984],
        [9987],
        [9990],
        [9993]]])

model.predict(x_test[-1:])
result is: array([[10141.571, 10277.236]], dtype=float32)
```

How can the vall_acc be 1 if the result is so far from the truth, result was

```
step    1          2
true [9996,      9999     ]
pred [10141.571, 10277.236]
```

Comment: You need to fully define the learning problem, its not clear to me what are the inputs and outputs of the model ( and the training data), is this regression or classification? If its regression then it makes no sense to look at accuracy

Comment: yes indeed it is a regression task as you can see here ```model.add(Dense(2))``` so what metric should be used for regression than?

Comment: No metric is needed for regression, the loss itself is a metric

Comment: You may find the discussion in [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse) useful. And indeed, as @MatiasValdenegro says, you don't need any additional metric for regression - the loss itself is a metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accuracy metric is only valid for classification tasks**. Therefore, if you use accuracy as the metric in a regression tasks, the reported metric values may not be valid at all. From your code, I feel that you are having a regression task, so this shouldn't be used.

Below is a list of the metrics that you can use in Keras on regression problems.

```
Mean Squared Error: mean_squared_error, MSE or mse
Mean Absolute Error: mean_absolute_error, MAE, mae
Mean Absolute Percentage Error: mean_absolute_percentage_error, MAPE, mape
Cosine Proximity: cosine_proximity, cosine
```

You can read about some theory at [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142873/how-to-determine-the-accuracy-of-regression-which-measure-should-be-used) and see some keras exampler code at [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/custom-metrics-deep-learning-keras-python/).

Sorry, little short of time, but I am sure these links will really help you. :)

Comment: yes it is a regression task so what metric do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

By the range of your true/predicted values and used loss - it seems like you're trying to solve regression problem, not classification.

So if I understood you correctly - you're trying to predict two numeric values based on input - instead of predicting, which of two classes is valid for these input.

If so - you shouldn't use accuracy metric. Because it'll just compare indices of maximal input for each input sample/prediction (a bit simplified). E.g. 9996 < 9999 and 10141.571 < 10277.236.