# ML Model giving me Zero accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm testing an ML model on a small dataset

```
data = pd.read_csv("house.csv")
x=data.iloc[:,0:3]
y=data["price"]
sd=preprocessing.scale(x)
#print(sd)
#print(data.head())

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(3,)))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.8), "mean_squared_error", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(sd,y,epochs=100)
yp=model.predict(sd)
data ["pred"] = yp
```

but when the model starts training it gave me accuracy Zero and the loss is unbelievable !!

> Epoch 100/100 32/47 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss:
>   125331226624.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 47/47 [==============================] - 0s 85us/step - loss:
>   131038484959.3192 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

here is the dataset https://uinedu-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/26636_myoffice_site/EWXspQfJBUVErTuYUuupaUoBO7kY8n1T5j-8I7k_V2zzMQ?e=lJvwaI

Comment: Two things seem odd, your dataset is really, truly small and your netwrok is really simple. Try to change those two things and look if you can see improvements

Comment: Accuracy is a classification metric, you are not doing classification but regression.

Comment: As Matias says; for details, see [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comment, `accuracy` **is not** a regression metric.

To evaluate a regression model, here is some of the metrics you can use:

- Mean Squared Error (MSE)
- Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)
- Mean Absolute Error (MAE)
- R Squared (R²)
- Adjusted R Squared (R²)
- Mean Square Percentage Error (MSPE)
- Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)
- Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error (RMSLE)

This great story on medium explains all of these metrics https://medium.com/@george.drakos62/how-to-select-the-right-evaluation-metric-for-machine-learning-models-part-1-regrression-metrics-3606e25beae0

A shorter explanation can be found here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142873/how-to-determine-the-accuracy-of-regression-which-measure-should-be-used

In keras

```py
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.8), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```