# Creating an ANN to predict stock return using value metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

First off, I'm new to Python and Machine learning, but I want to dive into it head first with a practical example (one which I'm sure many will have attempted before me).

I  have a dataset with 300+ stocks, 4 value metrics for each stock (recorded 3 years ago) and the stock price increase over the last 3 years.

**My goal?** Creating a ML model that estimates 3-year stock return based on fundamental/value metrics (ex. Price/Book, Price/Equity, FCF growth etc.).

The dataset looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBC2K.png

**My challenges?**

I'm doing something wrong during the training of the model, because I get this as output during training:

```
Epoch 1/100
8/8 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
```

When trying to predict a value

```
X_predict = [[1.43, 0.73, 0.37, -0.92]]
print(seann.predict(sc.transform(X_predict)))
```

I get output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 63ms/step
[[nan]]
```

**I think my error lies in the following:**

1. Standardising the input data

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

2. Finding the right parameters to initialise the model

```
seann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
seann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, activation='relu'))
seann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, activation='relu'))
seann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
seann.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Accuracy is a classification metric, NOT a regression metric. 
Read:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60598706/9520776

Comment: In addition to the potential error causes you listed, dying RELU might also be worth checking for.