# Validation accuracy reaches 1 with very high loss

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I have 3 very specific questions:

1. I am training a regression model-the dateset is small (300)-, and getting a validation accuracy of 1.00 in the 4th epoch till the last ! and training accuracy 0.9957 at the last epoch, while the loss is actually big it is 33 , so I don't know how both the accuracy and loss are very high!
   using optimizer ADAM and loss (mean_absolute_error)
2. When scaling the inputs, some values turn to negative despite I don't have any negative value, is that reasonable?And I noticed some similar numbers are not the same after scaling.
3. when I predict, I should scale the data I am going to predict at the same manner I scaled the inputs,no ? but how can I make sure of that as the inputs are all scaled related to each other in all the rows -as I understand-.

   ```
   array=SData.to_numpy()
   array
   ```

> array([[  6.25    ,   6.25    ,   6.25    , ...,   8.11521 ,
> 13.525349,
> 744.421033],
> [  6.25    ,   6.25    ,   6.25    , ...,   8.989118,  14.981864,
> 744.484697],
> [  6.25    ,   6.25    ,   6.25    , ...,   8.931293,  14.885489,
> 744.484629],
> ...,
> [  6.160831,   8.157965,   9.184461, ...,   6.170488,  10.284147,
> 938.598232],
> [  6.160831,   8.157965,   9.184461, ...,  12.417958,  20.696597,
> 938.291951],
> [  6.160831,   8.157965,   9.184461, ...,   6.007829,  10.013048,
> 938.103987]])
>
> ```
> unscaled_inputs=array[:,:9]
> unscaled_inputs
> targets=array[:,9:]
> unscaled_inputs array([[ 6.25    ,  6.25    ,  6.25    , ...,  6.25    ,  6.25    ,
>      0.      ],
>    [ 6.25    ,  6.25    ,  6.25    , ...,  6.25    ,  6.25    ,
>     15.      ],
>    [ 6.25    ,  6.25    ,  6.25    , ...,  6.25    ,  6.25    ,
>     30.      ],
>    ...,
>    [ 6.160831,  8.157965,  9.184461, ...,  8.640023,  8.996907,
>     45.      ],
>    [ 6.160831,  8.157965,  9.184461, ...,  8.640023,  8.996907,
>     60.      ],
>    [ 6.160831,  8.157965,  9.184461, ...,  8.640023,  8.996907,
>     75.      ]])
> ```

```
scaled_inputs=preprocessing.scale(unscaled_inputs)
scaled_inputs
```

> array([[ 0.64061068, -1.55811375, -1.96681483, ..., -0.96073795,
> -1.709721  , -1.46385011],
> [ 0.64061068, -1.55811375, -1.96681483, ..., -0.96073795,
> -1.709721  , -0.87831007],
> [ 0.64061068, -1.55811375, -1.96681483, ..., -0.96073795,
> -1.709721  , -0.29277002],
> ...,
> [ 0.35930701,  1.56499191,  1.66411229, ...,  0.76559569,
> 0.84111767,  0.29277002],
> [ 0.35930701,  1.56499191,  1.66411229, ...,  0.76559569,
> 0.84111767,  0.87831007],
> [ 0.35930701,  1.56499191,  1.66411229, ...,  0.76559569,
> 0.84111767,  1.46385011]])

```
shuffled_indicies=np.arange(scaled_inputs.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(shuffled_indicies)
shuffled_indicies
```

> array([257, 191,  37, 128,  72, 247, 161, 252, 140, 264, 258, 255,
> 278,
> 148, 231, 186,  31,  83, 230, 175, 121, 156, 151, 256, 192, 200,
> 66,  59, 199,   9, 223, 157, 214,  73,  92,  61,  60, 139,  47,
> 280, 202, 104, 110,  22,  39, 197,  81, 225,  69,  94, 284,  18,
> 113, 187, 267, 173,  91,  90, 111, 180, 144,  20, 287, 153, 131,
> 103, 268, 172, 260, 193, 141, 224, 179,  87, 106,  96, 274,  85,
> 89, 105,  84,  75,  15, 160,  52,  24, 126,  16, 235, 124,  44,
> 40, 249,  34,  63, 219,  11, 198, 149, 118, 277, 222, 238, 209,
> 127, 272, 184, 107,   5, 146, 169,  57, 116, 170,  82,  23, 207,
> 174, 188,  88, 206,   7,  36, 226,  86, 150, 276, 163,  62,  12,
> 253, 204,  45,  74, 210,  14, 108, 195, 196,   4, 109, 263, 241,
> 147,  78, 176,  33,  10, 232, 248,  42,  43,  50,  97, 270, 117,
> 254, 181, 201, 266, 182,  38, 211, 218, 212,  26, 239,  41,  55,
> 275,  77, 189,  30, 122,  80,  58, 271,  19, 119, 158, 154, 177,
> 53,  70, 265,  99, 205, 165, 250, 178,  49, 213, 136, 240,   6,
> 208,  25,  32, 217, 246, 285, 237,   3, 227, 155, 190, 259, 159,
> 269, 138, 167, 216, 234,  64, 281, 133, 137, 166,   2,  54, 112,
> 13,  65, 279, 114,  95, 100,   1, 125, 282, 185, 145, 102,  29,
> 135,   0, 101,  71, 164,  17,  28, 130,  68, 262,  56, 245, 129,
> 244, 236, 283,  67,   8,  79, 134,  35,  51, 120, 168, 194,  21,
> 27,  98, 251, 115, 273, 123, 233,  76, 286, 228, 243, 220, 162,
> 142, 229, 203, 152, 143, 221, 242, 171,  48,  93, 132, 183, 215,
> 261,  46])

```
shuffled_inputs=scaled_inputs[shuffled_indicies]
shuffled_targets=targets[shuffled_indicies]
#define the numcer of observations
observations_count=shuffled_inputs.shape[0]
# 80 10 10 Rule
train_count=int(0.8 * observations_count)
validation_count=int(0.1 * observations_count )
test_count=observations_count-train_count-validation_count

    train_inputs=shuffled_inputs[:train_count]
    train_targets=shuffled_targets[:train_count]
   validation_inputs=shuffled_inputs[train_count:train_count+validation_count]
 validation_targets=shuffled_targets[train_count:train_count+validation_count]
    test_inputs=shuffled_inputs[train_count+validation_count:]
    test_targets=shuffled_targets[train_count+validation_count:]


np.savez('Sample_Data_Train',inputs=train_inputs,targets=train_targets)
    np.savez('Sample_Data_Validation',inputs=validation_inputs,targets=validation_targets)
    np.savez('Sample_Data_Test',inputs=test_inputs,targets=test_targets)
npz=np.load(r"C:\Users\dai_k\OneDrive\Desktop\GRASSHOPPERS\Second semester\Thesis\samplenpz\Sample_Data_Train.npz")
Processed_train_inputs=npz['inputs'].astype(np.float)
processed_train_targets=npz['targets'].astype(np.float)

npz1=np.load(r"C:\Users\dai_k\OneDrive\Desktop\GRASSHOPPERS\Second semester\Thesis\samplenpz\Sample_Data_Validation.npz")
processed_validation_inputs=npz1['inputs'].astype(np.float)
processed_validation_targets=npz1['targets'].astype(np.float)

npz2=np.load(r"C:\Users\dai_k\OneDrive\Desktop\GRASSHOPPERS\Second semester\Thesis\samplenpz\Sample_Data_Test.npz")
processed_test_inputs=npz2['inputs'].astype(np.float)
processed_test_targets=npz2['targets'].astype(np.float)


output_size=8
hidden_layer_size=100 # START WITH ANY WIDTH - This is a hyperbarameter

model=tf.keras.Sequential([
                          tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
                          tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
                          tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='relu')
                           ]) 

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size=8
max_epochs=30
early_stopping=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping()

model.fit(Processed_train_inputs,
         processed_train_targets,
         batch_size=batch_size,
         epochs=max_epochs,
         callbacks=[early_stopping],
         validation_data=(processed_validation_inputs, processed_validation_targets),
         verbose=2 )
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Accuracy is **meaningless** in regression problems and it should **not** be used; please see [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse) (the rationale for MAE is the exact same).

Answer (score 0):

It is a regression problem, and you used MAE loss function. So, it is not possible the value of loss very small ( fraction, like in classification loss) and I think it is logical for regression type analysis.

You are standardizing your dataset not normalization. Normalization usually means to scale a variable to have a set of values between 0 and 1, while standardization transforms data to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of 1. So, using [scale](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html) you are converting your data zero mean, so that happens. You can use [normalizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) or using raw coding for data normalization.

Yes, you should standardize your data while predicting. Otherwise, due to training and testing data variation (as data distribution is different in train and test) performance will poor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you answer is super helpful :) , but is the validation accuracy logical to be 1.00 ? , also at the last point you mean I should normalize the data not standardize ?

Comment: Your model is over/under fitted and it isn't not good for your val_acc. Depends on dataset, it may works better in normalizing or standardizing or using both of them.

Comment: maybe the overfitting is happening due to the size of the data If i am not wrong, as I am using early stopping also

Comment: sorry i don't understand ! what behavior ?!! My upvote is recorded since I am new and don't have enough reputation to vote, in any case thanks for the help

Comment: Then, You should tune the hyperparameters of your model.